# How to force a mod_rewrite RewriteRule to display as rewritten even if the un-rewritten url is entered

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

is it possible to make it so that url rewrites are forced?

Here is an example of what works, http://localhost/home/ goes to http://localhost/index.php?page=home but the url stays the same to the user.

What I can't get to work is forcing http://localhost/index.php?page=home to display as 
http://localhost/home/.

I don't know if I'm using the right terminology, but I want it so that if you type the non rewritten url, I want the rewritten url to appear in the user's browser.

Here is what I have working so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/?$ index.php?page=$1&a=$2&b=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$ index.php?page=$1&a=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: You cannot change the url entered by the user without reloading the page. I do not think a rewrite rule will help you in this scenario. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: I think you take it the wrong way: if you think about it, you just don't want users to access directly to `index.php`, right? Just do a **`404`** and in the **`404`** display some links that **really** work. Nice 404 have messages like "Did you mean `http://localhost/home/`"? ...

Answer (score 1):

That's what the [R] flag is for.  If you have a correctly-working rewrite, you'll want to add [R] to your other flags at the end of your RewriteRule.

Comment: Won't the [R] make it "http://localhost/index.php?page=home" if i enter "http://localhost/home/"? If it does, this is the opposite effect. I want it to become "http://localhost/home/" when i enter "http://localhost/index.php?page=home" to the user's browser. I want this so that my links work whether mod_rewrite is enabled or not. _On a side note, I don't know why there are semicolons after my links in this comment, ignore them..._

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some code to your index.php.

Look at the `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']` variable for your answer.  When you enter "localhost/index.php?page=home" in your browser, `SCRIPT_URL` should equal '/index.php'.  If you enter "localhost/home", `SCRIPT_URL` should equal '/home'.  You can do a check for this in your PHP script and redirect appropriately from there.

Comment: As for a .htaccess solution to the problem, it's something I'm still looking for.