# mod_rewrite not changing URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I just started working with Apache's mod_rewrite module and I've run into a problem I can't seem to figure out.  What I want is to have the address bar display clean URLs either when a user manually types in the URL or when the page is linked to.  Right now I get clean URLs when they're typed in but the query string still shows up in the address bar when the page is linked to.  For example:

Typing in, myDomain.com/first takes me the page at myDomain.com/index.php?url=first and displays myDomain.com/first in the address bar.

But, when clicking a link like href="index.php?url=first". The address bar displays myDomain.com/index.php?url=first when I want it to display myDomain.com/first.

Here is my .htaccess file located in the same folder as my index file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is my index file:

```
<?php
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/'); // Define the root directory for use in includes 
require_once (ROOT_DIR . 'library/bootstrap.php');

$url = strtolower($_GET['url']);

include(ROOT_DIR . 'views/headerView.php');

switch($url)
{
    case "first": include(ROOT_DIR . 'views/firstPageView.php');
        break;
    case "second": include(ROOT_DIR . 'views/secondPageView.php');
        break;
    default: include(ROOT_DIR . 'views/homeView.php');
} 

include 'views/footerView.php';
?>
```

And here is homeView.php:

```
<p>This is the home page.</p>
<p>To the first page. <a href="index.php?url=first">First Page</a></p>
<p>To the second page. <a href="index.php?url=second">Second Page</a></p>
```

Any advice or help on my linking problem would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a mod_rewrite RewriteRule to display as rewritten even if the un-rewritten url is entered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313535/how-to-force-a-mod-rewrite-rewriterule-to-display-as-rewritten-even-if-the-un-re)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, when clicking a link like href="index.php?url=first". The address
>   bar displays myDomain.com/index.php?url=first when I want it to
>   display myDomain.com/first.

You'll have to link to the "clean" URL. Remember, you're not redirecting here. You're rewriting! That mean's you'll have to change this:

```
<p>This is the home page.</p>
<p>To the first page. <a href="index.php?url=first">First Page</a></p>
<p>To the second page. <a href="index.php?url=second">Second Page</a></p>
```

To something like this:

```
<p>This is the home page.</p>
<p>To the first page. <a href="/url/first">First Page</a></p>
<p>To the second page. <a href="/url/second">Second Page</a></p>
```

Comment: Yeah, I can get it to work the way I want it to by just using href="first" but that doesn't seem like its the right way to do it.  Maybe I'm just used to having more than one word in a URL?

Comment: It all depends on what "First" means really. First what? As long as the URL makes sense in the context of your application, it should be fine.

Comment: I'm using "first" as a place holder for the actual name of the page.  But the word first or the name of the page is what I use in the switch statement in the index file to know which page to include.

Answer (score 0):

Look those two lines :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

It mean : *if url point on a real file or folder, don't try following rules.*

When you use `myDomain.com/index.php?url=first`, it point on a real file : `index.php`. Then, your rules won't be tried.

You **must** always use clean url like `myDomain.com/first` in your code.

Comment: I tried commenting those two lines out and it still does the same thing?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You shouldn't remove those line, but use `myDomain.com/first` instead of `myDomain.com/index.php?url=first` in your code.

Comment: Ahh...  Got it, I did have it set up that way but I thought that having only href="first" didn't seem right because if mod_rewrite ever got turned off or didn't work, all of the links would break.  Thank you.

Comment: If `mod_rewrite` don't work, it means Apache is down, then your full website don't work, and you don't really have to care about url at this moment ;)